# Enabling 000-default.conf breaks namebased vhost

Tags: apache2, vhost

I have two sites on a server: `dev.example.com` and `example.com` - the latter has a ServerAlias of `*.example.com`. All domains are SSL-enabled, and all requests to port 80 is redirected to HTTPS. The `example.com` site is a proxy of an old site, on a different server, that is about to be decommissioned.

`dev.example.com` works like a charm

`http://example.com` is for some reason "caught" by the `000-default.conf` configuration (HTTPS is not), but `http://www.example.com` (the server alias `*.example.com`) is NOT "caught" by `000-default.conf`, and is working as expected.

If I disable the `000-default.conf`, everything seems to work, except for `https://dev.example.com/phpmyadmin` (which DOES work with 000-default enabled - I think I understand why)

`example.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.example.com

    Redirect 301 / https://dev.example.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com

    Redirect 302 / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

And the `000-default.conf`, which seems to break `example.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`example-ssl.conf`: (this one does not seem to have any problems, but included here to be sure)

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName dev.example.com

        DocumentRoot "/var/www/example/wwwroot"
        Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
        Alias /index.php /var/www/example/index.php
        Alias /import-data.php /var/www/example/import.php
        <Directory /var/www/example/wwwroot>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None

            Require all granted

            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /var/www/example/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/example/logs/access.log combined

        ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/var/www/example/

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.example.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName example.com

        <Location "/">
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        #anonymised IP to protect the guilty:
        ProxyPass http://172.0.0.10/
        ProxyPassReverse http://example.com/

        AddOutputFilterByType INFLATE;SUBSTITUTE;DEFLATE text/html
        Substitute "s|http://example.com/|/|iq"
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        </Location>

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.example.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Why does `http://example.com` show Apache's default page, while `http://www.example.com` is - as expected - redirected to `https://example.com`?

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server dev.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost dev.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example-ssl.conf:2)
         port 443 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example-ssl.conf:35)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost dev.example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost example.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.conf:7)
                 wild alias *.example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

First start with the output of the command `apachectl -S`. It shows you all your virtual hosts and the files they come from.

The first listed virtual host in the output is the 'default virtual host'. I am guessing this is the one in `000-default.conf`. If so, then that virtual host has no `ServerName` and so will take the one from the global (server) context, or the hostname of the machine. If this is `example.com` then it means requests for this domain will land on this virtual host. If is is not the show us the output of `apachectl -S` to help troubleshoot.

**Explanation:** This is just the way virtual hosts work. Apachae tries to match the hostname used (actually the contents of the 'Host' HTTP header) against any `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` and once it finds a match that virtual host receives the request. If no match is found the first virtual host listed is used. So if you have two virtual host with the same `ServerName` only the first will can be accessed using that name.

**Best practise:** Give every virtual host a `ServerName` to make sure you explicitly know which requests will land on each one, and every time you make a configuration change run `apachectl -S`

Comment: `apachectl -S` added to question.

I'm not sure I follow - the relevant virtualhosts all have servername? What I don't understand is why the fallback 000-default.conf is triggered by a request that has a matching vhost?

Comment: If you look at the directives between the <VirtualHost> tags in 000-default.conf you'll see theres is no explicit ServerName, so it is taking a default name from the global context. Look at the output, you have two virtual hosts with the same ServerName.

Comment: Okay, yes, I see that. But it's the fallback that's only supposed to trigger, when there is no other match? And it's supposed to be the catch-all, and many places I read "do not mess with `000-default.conf`" - adding an explicit ServerName to `000-default.conf` would cause it to not work as intended?

Comment: No its not a fall back, The first ServerName or ServerAlias that matches is used, hence why you lost `example.com`. Adding an Explicit ServerName to `000-default.conf` will indeed fix things, as long as its not the same as any of your others :) Using the IP of the server is a good choice normally.

Comment: From Apache documentation: "When a request is received, the server first maps it to the best matching `<VirtualHost>` based on the local IP address and port combination only. Non-wildcards have a higher precedence. If no match based on IP and port occurs at all, the "main" server configuration is used."